# passing counter variable back to node js server from html page

Tags: javascript, node.js

noob node JS question..

I have the following server currently running:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

So the server reads my index.html file and runs it on the server. In that HTML page I have some basic javascript written(along with HTML) and it has a counter variable which increments by 1 whenever a button is clicked and the counter is displayed on the HTML page.

My question is: is it possible to send the counter variable from the HTML file to the server or is it maybe possible to declare the counter variable on the server and then increment on the server and display it on the HTML page?

To clarify: basically I want to click a button on the HTML page, have the counter go counter++ and then have access to this counter variable on the server side.

Is there anyway to do this preferably without any plugins?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var counter = 0;

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) { 
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"}); 
        if(request.url == "/countup"){
            counter++; 
            response.write("Counted UP");
        } else {
            if(request.url == "/getnumber"){
                 response.write(counter);
            } else {
                 response.write(html);
            }
        } 
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

Now when you request `http://localhost:8080/getnumber` you will get the current number.
If you request `http://localhost:8080/countup` the counter will count one up and send bakc "Counted UP".
And for everything else you will get your index.html file.

To connect this with your button you need to perform an ajax request which is well explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp).

Best regards

Dustin

PS.: Please have a look on [express.JS](http://expressjs.com/).